# Execute query that normally runs on a single ID for every ID

Tags: mysql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT ABS(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(),  
        (SELECT MAX(`Time`) FROM ddHistorical WHERE ID = '5')  
    )
)
```

I want to run that on every ID in my database, how would I do that?

Comment: Are you saying all records in your table, then why not skip the where clause... or just say where 1=1

Comment: Remove `WHERE ID='5'`

Comment: @skv:  Actually I've tried that.   It returns: Subquery returned more than one row.

Comment: "0 7 17:25:01 SELECT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), (SELECT MAX(`Time`) FROM ddHistorical group by ID)))
 LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1242
 Subquery returns more than 1 row"   The ddHistorical table contains a great deal of rows PK'd off ID.

Comment: @skv So next time before you go ahead and be rude, consider that not everyone's schema is simple.   Your comment had no forethought, nor was it really called for.   As such, it's contributed nothing and has been reported.  Thanks.

Comment: @Damien.Bell, WHy dont you limit the inner query `SELECT MAX(Time) FROM ddHistorical group by ID LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Reported for what? I wasnt rude, I was just questioning you, you should have reported the issue in your question, two people with more than 10K reputation have given you the obvious suggestion, you should report what you have tried in your question ALWAYS... I was rude at all.. whats rude in my comment

Comment: And I dont mind saying sorry if I hurt you, but the intention is to understand your thought and difficulty properly before everyone invests their time... I hope my query helps you... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ac0/3/0)

```
  SELECT Abs(Timestampdiff(minute, Now(), (SELECT Max( ` time ` ) 
                                         FROM   ddhistorical 
                                         WHERE  id = a.id 
                                         GROUP  BY id))) 
FROM   ddhistorical AS A 
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one.  Do you think you could show me how I would grab all the other columns using this query?   I've been reading up but subqueries make me crazy.

Comment: You are welcome, `SELECT id,ABS(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(),  
        (SELECT MAX(`Time`) FROM ddHistorical where id = a.id group by id)  
    ) 
) as time_since from ddHistorical as A group by id` gives id and time, which other columns do you want, please remember you need to group by each field that you will add to the list of fields

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), (SELECT MAX(`Time`) FROM ddHistorical
```